# Spring | Hibernate | Transaction management with AspectJ

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat, aspectj

We are working on a new project using Spring, Hibernate and Transaction management using AspectJ (@Transactional annotations) and we are not sure what is the best practices weaving options to go.

We've started with the LTW  and placed the tomcat Loader, it worked fine.. but then we thought that it may be less risky to have compile time weaving which instruments and *.classes and not on load time (in memory), so it will done just one time and not when on the tomcat startup. This is done via Maven aspectj-maven-plugin plugin.

Can you please advice ? 
What are the pros and cons of using those weaving options ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This is not a discussion forum but a Q/A platform, so your question does not have **the** correct answer, it rather sparks discussion. I am trying to elaborate a bit anyway.*

You basically already stated the main facts about LTW versus CTW. I am failing to see why LTW should be more risky than CTW, though. It slows down your server start-up, but the risk is the same as with CTW because the resulting byte code is also the same. Or are you talking about the risk that maybe more code gets (e.g. 3rd party libraries) woven than you intend? In that case yet, CTW keeps you on the safe side and you have more control over what should be woven. It should also speed up your server start-up time in comparison with LTW.

So if you have no compelling reasons to use LTW, such as the wish to dynamically intercept code you are unaware of during development, go ahead and use CTW and you are on the safe side, as long as you are fine with adjusting your build process accordingly. AspectJ Maven plugin is pretty straightforward to use, so that should not be a big deal. You can still switch to LTW as needed and *when* needed. OTOH, if you are using LTW now and are fine with the server start-up time, maybe there is no need to switch. If unsure, try both approaches and compare the results. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I read that the result is the same on both options, but on the other hand, The LTW happens on tomcat start-up so it looks more dynamically/Risky process than the CTW which happened just one time! When working on local environment and then going to production environment, there is no differences between how the LTW is working ? It must behave the same and give the same result ?
While with CTW, my thought was that once you're compiling with AJC, the bytecode will be the same on all of the environments so we will not have any surprises...

What do you think ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is easier to control weaving in CTW than in LTW scenario because you are never 100% sure that your local or testing stage ist configure exactly like the production stage. So if you want to play it safe, use CTW unless something forces you to use LTW. LTW can still be used optionally for tracing or profiling aspects, if the need arises. Production aspects can be woven via CTW. Use the best of both worlds as you need it.